# Elemento HTML dentro de um ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, razor

Olá, gostaria de saber se é possível criar um elemento HTML dentro de um `ActionLink`, por exemplo:

Para criar um link em um menu com `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Classificação Financeira", "Index", "ClassificacaoFinanceira")
```

Mas eu preciso criar um elemento para colocar uma figura no menu e se eu for fazer com a tag `a` ficaria assim:

```
<a href="/ClassificacaoFinanceira"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i> Classificação Financeira</a>
```

Mas eu gostaria de fazer isso usando o `ActionLink`, tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Isso não te ajudaria: <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ClassificacaoFinanceira")"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i></a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um método de extensão no seu [HTMLHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx) e formatar o seu elemento da forma que precisar!

***Como seria um extensão da TagHelper:***

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class Methods
    {
        public static String ControllerName(this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper)
        {
            return HtmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }
        public static String ControllerName(this AjaxHelper AjaxHelper)
        {
            return AjaxHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }
        public static String ActionName(this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper)
        {
            return HtmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        }
        public static String ActionName(this AjaxHelper AjaxHelper)
        {
            return AjaxHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        }
        public static object GetValue<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
            where TModel : class
        {
            TModel model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
            if (model == null)
            {
                return default(string);
            }
            Func<TModel, TProperty> func = expression.Compile();
            return func(model);
        }
        public static IHtmlString ButtonEdit(this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper, String Description, String ActionName, String Title, params object[] routeValues)
        {
            string routes = string.Empty;
            if (routeValues.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (object route in routeValues)
                {
                    if (routes == string.Empty)
                    {
                        routes += route;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        routes += "/" + route;
                    }
                }
            }
            string _button = string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" target=\"_self\" title=\"{1}\">{2}</a>",
                string.Format("/{0}/{1}/{2}", ControllerName(HtmlHelper), ActionName, routes), Title, Description);
            return new HtmlString(_button);
        }
    }
}
```

Observe que existe vários métodos para auxilio e que no método `ButtonEdit` e a nova *tag* que eu criei.

***Como chamar na sua View:***

```
@Html.ButtonEdit("Cadastro", "Index", "", null)
```

Comment: O problema é aquela classe fixa ali.

Comment: Não entendi @CiganoMorrisonMendez ?

Comment: Falo disto: `class=\"btn btn-primary\"`. Se eu quiser usar outra classe, não posso. Vamos supor que meu link não seja um botão.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez no meu sistema foi aplicado essa CSS como padrão, e isso não é um problema é a forma como eu vi o meu sistema de botões e padronização. Só lembrando que isso é um exemplo e deve ser alterado para adequar ao que ele precisa fazer no sistema dele! Isso não é um problema é uma customização minha que pra você possa ser diferente.

Comment: Só reafirmando @CiganoMorrisonMendez o meu botão em todo o sistema ficará com esse CSS para identificação e normativas, utilizado pela equipe de desenvolvimento (Foi decidido que esse botão tem essa cor, tamanho e estilo).

Answer (score 3):

A maneira mais interessante que achei pra resolver o problema é criando minhas próprias extensões para o `HtmlHelper`. Pro seu caso, que você quer usar o FontAwesome no link, o código abaixo resolve:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MeuProjeto.Extensions
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlString FontAwesomeActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText,
            string actionName, string fontAwesomeClass, object routeValues = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            return FontAwesomeActionLink(htmlHelper, linkText, actionName, null, fontAwesomeClass, routeValues,
                htmlAttributes);
        }

        public static IHtmlString FontAwesomeActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText,
            string actionName, string controllerName, string fontAwesomeClass, object routeValues = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            var targetUrl = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, actionName, controllerName, ObjectToDictionary(routeValues), htmlHelper.RouteCollection, htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, true);
            return new MvcHtmlString(GenerateLink(linkText, targetUrl, fontAwesomeClass, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)));
        }

        private static string GenerateLink(string linkText,
            string targetUrl,
            string fontAwesomeClass,
            IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes
        )
        {
            var a = new TagBuilder("a");

            a.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
            a.MergeAttribute("href", targetUrl);

            var i = new TagBuilder("i");

            i.MergeAttribute("class", "fa " + fontAwesomeClass);
            a.InnerHtml = i.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal) + " " + linkText;

            return a.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        }
    }
}
```

Registre a extensão no `web.config` **dentro do diretório `Views`**:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System" />
        <add namespace="MeuProjeto.Extensions" /> <!-- Este -->
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Uso:

```
@Html.FontAwesomeActionLink("Classificação Financeira", "Indice", "ClassificacaoFinanceira", "fa fa-bar-chart")
```